# Where can I find up-to-date documentation about the WCF Web API?

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-web-api

I've been strugling with WCF to do REST the way I want it to work. And apparently so has quite a few others. I've heard about the [WCF Web Api project](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP), but wrongly dismissed it without looking too closely at it. Sadly, now that I'm looking at it I find that the documentation is rather outdated. Like, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-web-apis-http-your-way.aspx) has some nice information, but classes have changed, parameters have changed, in short, design has changed.

So I've been using an old example of how to plug in Json.NET (newtonsoft) as my serializier, only to realize that after I had it working, it wouldn't work for my IErrorHandler. Further I had a problem with how to [Deserialize a string from the uri template to an operation Type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214980/deserialize-a-string-from-the-uri-template-to-an-operation-type-parameter).

It appears however that I should be able to solve these two problems (and presumably many others that I haven't stumbled over yet) by using the media formatter extension point and what's referred to as `Processor<..>`s in outdated documentation, which is now `HttpOperationHandler<..>`s unless I've missunderstood.

My problem is rather basic, I can't figure out how to correctly configure my IIS-hosted app to use my operation handler, assuming I've implemented it correctly. Since it feels rather dumb to ask for instructions on such a basic thing, I'll rather ask where I can find some documentation on how to do this sort of thing? (Explanations are welcome of course.)

I'm not after seing which classes exist, or what their methods are named with what parameters. I can see all that in my object browser. I need documentation for the overall design, and/or examples implicitly describing things like:

- How do the different classes in the API fit together?
- How can I configure from web.config?
- Must I rather do a custom HttpServiceHostFactory?
- What and how are you meant to use the framework?
- How should I extend to reach what sort of goals?
- How should I configure to place the extensions in effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lack of answers I assume the documentation quite simply isn't ready.

I was looking for it on the codeplex site under the [Documentation](http://wcf.codeplex.com/documentation) tab, and found outdated stuff.

However, after familiarizing myself a bit with Codeplex I found out that the good stuff was in [this Discussion section](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/4885/web-api). Searching a bit in there helped a lot to be honest.

Concerning config-file configuration, I didn't find anything, so I'm assuming this will be added as the last thing before official release. Meaning I'll use the `HttpConfiguration` in a custom `HttpServiceHostFactory` for now.

The trick about the `HttpOperationHandler`s was twofold: Firstly I was throwing an exception in my operation and hadn't implemented a global `HttpErrorHandler` yet. (Doh!) Secondly I didn't know that the parameter name of HttpOperationHandler<..>.OnHandle had to match the name of the operation parameter.